# Cut string before a symbol with php

Tags: php

How can I cut the string before '(' sign with php

For example:
  $a = "abc dec g (gold)";

How can I cut the string become only "abc dec g"??

I tried to used this strstr($a, '(', true) but error display.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could do this, using [`explode`](http://www.php.net/explode):

```
list($what_you_want,) = explode('(', $str, 2);
```

Or you could also do this, using [`substr`](http://www.php.net/substr) and [`strpos`](http://www.php.net/strpos):

```
$what_you_want = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, '('));
```

The reason you got the error using [`strstr`](http://www.php.net/strstr) is because the last argument is not available unless you have PHP 5.3.0 or later.

Comment: You don't even need a $garbage variable: list($what_you_want, ) = explode('(', $str, 2); works as well.

Comment: Also, he said strstr($str, '(', true); doesn't work, so I assume he doesn't have 5.3.0…

Comment: Whoops, never mind that last comment—I must not have noticed the edit.

Comment: It's all good. Seems quite unlike PHP to allow that trailing comma in the list, I'm kinda shocked that works. Good to know, I guess.

Comment: perfect solution ;)

Answer (score 6):

```
$a=substr($a, 0, strpos($a, '('));
```

Answer (score 2):

How about [strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php):

`$topic = strstr('Some topic :: part to exclude', '::', TRUE);`

then

`$topic` = Some topic

Edit: right... 5.3+ only

Answer (score 1):

Using this piece of code is indeed a good solution:

```
$what_you_want = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, '('));
```

Still, I would like to point to the fact that it will cut your string at the first occurence of "(". Shoud you want to cut it at the LAST occurence of "(", you should use

```
$what_you_want = substr($str, 0, strrpos($str, '('));
```

I found it to be often the case when scrapping html content for example (because of nested tags).

Cheers,
Joan